# .AspNetApplicationCookie and ASP.NET_SessionId not created

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I have application developed in ASP.Net 4.5 Web forms.

My Issue is I have hosted this site in IIS and first login .AspNetApplicationCookie and ASP.NET_SessionId cookies are created and log-in works fine.

Let say if user clears browser history and tries again to log-in, these 2 cookies are not created and hence not able to go to next page. I have used 
default Application Cookie authentication.

I have tested IE, chrome and firefox browsers.

I tried to reset IIS and cookies are created again by site.

I have worked on some know issue

• installed framework from 4.0 to 4.5.
• Creating app_browser files specific to IE

I am stuck with this issue. Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: This article solved my issue. There is a bug in Microsoft's Owin implementation for System.Web https://github.com/KentorIT/owin-cookie-saver Thank you Anders Abel for your fix.